# Remove Extent lines from DiscretePlot?

Tags: plotting

For example,

```
DiscretePlot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}, ExtentSize -> Full]
```

[image]

How can I remove the blue lines on top of the bars? I only want the bars to be visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** TDIL: It turns out we can use a suboption (`LineColor` or `"LineColor"`)  for `PlotStyle` to style the lines:

```
DiscretePlot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}, ExtentSize -> Full, 
  PlotStyle -> "LineColor" -> None]
```

[image]

Another approach is to set `PlotStyle` to `None` and use `FillingStyle` with a setting that matches the default filling style without the `PlotStyle -> None` options:

```
DiscretePlot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}, ExtentSize -> Full, 
   PlotStyle -> None, 
   FillingStyle -> Opacity[.2, RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798]]]
```

> same picture

**Original answer:**

```
DiscretePlot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}, ExtentSize -> Full] /.  Line[x___] :> {}
```

[image]

Alternatively, use the option `ExtentElementFunction` with a setting, say `"Rectangle"`, that does not produce the unwanted lines:

```
DiscretePlot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}, ExtentSize -> Full, 
 ExtentElementFunction->"Rectangle", PlotStyle -> LightBlue]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Seems a bit extreme, but thanks. I was hoping there was an option one could use. If there are no more answers I'll accept yours.

Comment: @becko, i agree. Please see the new version with an alternative method.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use `ListLinePlot`

```
 ListLinePlot[Sin[Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/6]], InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
     Filling -> Axis, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0]}]
```

[image]